# Magento2: Layered navigation at top of category page

Tags: magento2, php, layered-navigation

In Magento2, I want layered navigation to be shown in the content area at the top of the product listing.
I managed to do it but simultaneously its showing in left sidebar too. I don't want to show it in left side bar. How can I hide it from left side bar and just keep above the product listing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which theme you are used ? custom or luma ?

Comment: Have you check below code, it is working or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display layer navigation on top in product list page.

> `<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content" before="-"/>`